# Hibernate is not persisting nested relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have 4 entities: Play, Actor, Play-representation and Category. 
Each play belongs to a category and play-representation associates a play with a theater and a number of actors at a given time.
    Here are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    private List<Play> playList = new ArrayList<Play>();
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "actor")
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "profile_picture")
    private String profilePicturePath;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "play_representation_category",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "play_representation_id")})
    private Set<PlayRepresentation> playRepresentations = new HashSet<>(0);
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "play")
public class Play {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "image_paths")
    private String imagePaths;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Category category;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "play_representation")
public class PlayRepresentation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "play_id")
    private Play play;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "theater_id")
    private Theater theater;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Timestamp airingDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "play_representation_category",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "play_representation_id", nullable=false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "actor_id", nullable=false)})
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>(0);
```

The issue I'm having is that hibernate is trying to find a relationship between play_representation and category! I've been trying to persist the relationship for the plays but it seems I got that wrong and can't figure out the best way to do it...It's a postgresql db by the way.

I am still learning, so if you have any other tips regarding the code I've shared, please let me know!

Edit: error is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "play_representation_category" does not exist
  Position: 281
```

Comment: and the error message is ?!

Comment: Your ManyToMany is bidirectional yet you haven't put `mappedBy` to link them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need a mappedBy, it was actually a typo - I wrote play_representation_category instead of play_representation_actors. Pretty stupid, huh? At least I finally found it :)

Comment: well you do need a mappedBy if that relation is BIDIRECTIONAL. Otherwise it is two independent relations, and you'll get the problem later

Comment: Ok, I will check that out! Thanks!